# How to hide HUD without removing subtitles?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I'm aware I can remove some stuff like floating markers and crosshairs, but I want to do a more immersive role-playing gameplay on my Xbox 360 with no HUD at all, except the subtitle, because I'm still learning english and It's better for me to read than just listen.

I tried putting HUD Opacity  to zero, but the subtitles disappear and when I make the opacity level higher, I see the compass, which breaks my playthrough.

Comment: On PC you could use console commands to hide the compass and crosshairs and such, but on 360 you're stuck with the options provided. If the HUD opacity doesn't work you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't on Xbox. The game options are what they are, and you've discovered that they're insufficient to do what you want.

This is even more evident when you look at this problem on PC, where players wanting subtitles and an immersive no-HUD experience need to use mods to achieve it (and pretty complicated mods, at that). Since Xbox Skyrim can't have mods, you're out of luck.